# Bootstrap 3 RC2 visible- and hidden- don't work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tested visible-xs and visible-small and neither work.

http://jsfiddle.net/kgxCH/

```
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
         <h1>Some text</h1>

        <p class="lead">More text</p>
        <p class="visible-small">   <a class="btn btn-large btn-success" href="tel:+0192234234234">Some text</a>
            <br />  <small class="text-muted">More text</small>

        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

I downloaded the Bootstrap 3 RC2 css file from their website three days ago. The documentation says that these exist and work.

The CSS file I downloaded contains visible-small but not visible-xs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use the **wrong** class name. Bootstrap provides `visible-sm` instead of `visible-small`. Change the class name and it works.

Another problem is I cannot find the `visible-xs` class inside your included CSS file (which is currently at: http://cja.org.uk/css/bootstrap.css). You should use the official CDN at http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-wip/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: Thanks. I was so annoyed with it that I missed that rather significant detail. I'll cope with visible-xs being missing for now.

Comment: There is an problem with your included CSS file, which has been updated in my answer. Please check again.

Comment: I've undone the edit. Just wanted to say that there's not even need for looking inside the CSS file, just go to the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: As I said, visible-xs isn't in my bootstrap.css file. I haven't changed this file sine downloading from the official website. I expect it's a mistake.

Comment: Also, I used the customiser (only to change fonts) to download my file so I can't use the CDN one. Also, I expect the wip CDN one will change over time. I want a stable file.